# ARRAYFORMULA Enter data if relevant but allow user input if not

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, array-formulas

I want a table to auto-fill if we have the data to input but allow user input if not. I've tried using an `ARRAYFORMULA` but if the user enters data into an empty field, the formula breaks.

Example:

```
    A     B     C
1|Date Policy *This cell contains formula below*
2| 1/1  High  6 Days
3| 2/1  Med   4 Days  
4| 3/1        
5| 4/1  Low   2 Days

=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B5="High","6 Days",IF(B2:B5="Med","4 Days",IF(B2:B5="Low","2 Days",""))))
```

I want the user to be able to input their own data in cell C4 (and B4) without it affecting the arrayformula

The empty row could be anywhere, it wont always be row 4

Comment: the only possible solution I can find is, I could store the Col:C data in another sheet (DATA) and have it populate with a `QUERY` function (somehow) and use an `onEdit` trigger to write any edits into the DATA page. I'm not sure how easy that would be (and I still need the Query to somehow know what's in Col B, I haven't solved that yet)

Comment: You'll either need to use a separate column or a script, there's no way to get around arrayformula #REF due to overwriting data in a cell. Is using three columns critical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is certainly not an exact answer to your question, but this solution allows you to do without using scripts - the user can enter data in another column (here column `D`) on this line, and the formula will search the result in `B` and if it is empty, then in `D`

`=ArrayFormula(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2:B5,G1:H3,2,false),VLOOKUP(D2:D5,G1:H3,2,false)))`

[image]